# Electron Affinity trends

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electron-affinity

Imagine an arrangement of atomic orbitals in an alternate universe, in which the s subshell contains 2 orbitals instead of 1, and the p subshell contains 4 orbitals rather than 3. In which groups would you expect the anomalously low electron affinities to occur?

My thoughts are groups 3 and 7, due to the fact that they are "one away" from filling up their subshell. The *groups* would look like:

s: _ _ _ _  ... p: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

However, the answer says 4 and 8. Is there something I'm missing?

Edit: in terms of electron configuration blanks, it would be
s: _ _ ... p: _ _ _ _

Comment: I am confused. Are you assuming that the energy ordering is the same? In other words, can you assume that it is 1s2s2p3s3p4s3d...etc?

Comment: Yes, but there's only one "shell" in this question. The order would still be s then p so ex. 2s4 2p7 for group 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After rediscovering my own question, I'm posting it as an answer for anyone else to reference or to correct.

---

Electron affinity (EA) refers to "the energy released when an atom in the gas phase accepts an electron." (Burdge, *Atoms First*, p.118)

Lower EA means that the process of accepting an electron is **not** energetically favorable. In other words, lower EA = less likely to accept an electron.

---

Groups 4 and 8, in this case, already have filled subshells. Adding an electron would place it in a new subshell that is higher in energy. The EA would be lower for these groups because of the "reluctance" of the atom to accept an additional electron.

Groups 3 and 7 have the anomalously *high* EAs, which might have been where the confusion was.

Comment: Since the periodic table (only maingroups) would then contain of 12 Groups, you are forgetting 2 (half s) and 12 (full p).